# How to do simple, reliable network messaging?

Tags: python, c, networking, network-programming

I'm using sockets for communication between various processes right now. Everything is running on the same machine, so there is no packet loss, and I also don't get read timeouts etc. The messages are typically small blobs of data (JSON, sometimes binary.) Now I want to do cross-machine communication. The client/server connection usually looks like this: The client tells the server to start some processing (passing in the task description), the server does the work and communicates progress back, and the client can optionally send a terminate message inbetween. Once finished, the server remains listening while the client is completely disconnected (i.e. the session is finished, starting a new task starts a new session.)

How should I implement the communication? I can easily continue using sockets over the network, but my understanding is that I'll now need to add lots of error handling to identify when a message didn't get through and communicate that somehow back to the server. All I want is just `send(message, target)` and rest assured that the complete message gets transmitted; plus some notification when the other side is dead. I've seen that there are a few libraries like zero-mq which claim to do exactly that but also much more, and I'm not sure if such a messaging library is actually necessary. Is there some easy to use library out there to do some basic communication?

I'm using C++ & Python, and BSD style-licenses are definitely strongly preferred for libraries. The library should also be rather stable, as the communication part is nothing really crucial and I'd like to be able to stick with one solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) guarantees all pagackes are passed to destination [It does the re-send for you if it didn't]. So, if you use it - it will probably take more time [compared to single machine], but correctness of msg transmissions remains.

Comment: So as long as I stick with TCP, I'm set?

Comment: There is a bizare edge case where the network is too jammed, and msg will not arrive no matter what - but, if this is the case - nothing you can do to get it passed. Other then that - yes, you are pretty much set with TCP.

Comment: You may have to add some error handling to cater for node failure (e.g. client or server goes down so the connection gets aborted). But other than that you should be fine with TCP.

Comment: I should get that information from `recv`, right? I.e. if the connection is dead, then `recv` will fail immediately & reliably?

Comment: It's not always possible to distinguish between a dead connection and one that is just really, really, slow. So, no, it will not always fail immediately (you need a timeout).

Comment: @Anteru: since not receiving any data is not an indication of failure, the only way to detect that the link is broken is to try to *write* something.  This can be done through [TCP keepalive](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) or it can be done through a ping/pong mechanism as part of your higher-level protocol.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/).  It has a simpler interface than pure BSD sockets, it more portable and has *excellent* documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) for an open source network communication library.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a message queue.

There are many, many solutions, of which just one is redis: http://redis.io