# Passing Variables from one pi to another

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pickle

I'm making a Skeeball program and boards that both work off of a raspberry pi and GPIO sensors with a tkinter gui.  The first table and program is working great and now I was thinking about the possibility of adding a second table with multiplayer games.

Each pi would have to talk to each other, preferably over a LAN network instead of using I2C or serial pins.  Basically I just need something mostly to pass variables from one pi to another.

My first thought was to use pickle to save to a shared network folder since I'm already using pickle to save my highscores.  I just have no clue how to set up a shared folder over raspbian and I'm guessing that probably a pretty bad approach to solving the problem.

I'm also really new when it comes to python and raspbian so sorry if this problem is something super easy all I could find online was how to have a pi talk with a windows pc or an arduino.

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: This question is probably too broad in its current form.  Using a shared folder for communication is sub-optimal.  You may want to do some reading on the topic of "messaging"; [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952837/how-to-do-simple-reliable-network-messaging) question may have some useful answer.

Comment: Set up a web server & quick website on each one? Nginx/Apache?

Comment: You don't need either of those. You have Python. It has its own HTTP server and client. Or you could talk directly with sockets.

Comment: any connection (HTTP or socket) blocks tkinter mainloop so you have to run it in thread.

Comment: looking at larsks other question he linked to, would ZeroMQ block Tkinter's mainloop? @furas

Comment: if `ZeroMQ` has non-blocking `get()` function and you don't have to wait for connection `ZeroMQ` then it can work.

Comment: @furas looks like it needs a mainloop or a while true to work correctly.  Is there anything that you would know of to pass a variable from one pi to the other without having to throw out tkinter and start over with a different gui?

Comment: if it needs `while true` then you can use `tk.after(miliseconds, function_name)` to run function periodically and simulate `while true` loop. Problem are only blocking functions like `socket.accept()` for server. BTW: you will have the same problem with any GUI - all GUIs use own `mainloop`. You can always use thread to run socket in separated thread and stop blocking main thread with tkinter mainloop.